# How can I use managed library in C++/CLI project

Tags: .net, c++-cli, pdf-generation, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have downloaded [`PDF Clown`](http://www.stefanochizzolini.it/en/projects/clown/index.html#Introduction) for .NET. I would like to use it in `C++/CLI` project. I tried to search about how can I configure this lib to be ready to used in my `C++/CLI` project. Actually, this is the first time for me in trying to add `managed` library in a `C++/CLI` project. I used to do it with classical way in mixed mode of `C++/CLI`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click the project, Properties, Common Properties, Framework and References.  Click the Add New Reference button.  Browse tab and select the DLL.  Big Red Arrow:

[image]

Comment: thank you, but by this way, do I need to put the dll files along with my application in each machine I use my app? or they will be embedded in my application and so no need to always carry them ?